# One of AWS sub domains not working, the one with dev (dev.example.com) is not working

Tags: angular, laravel, apache, amazon-s3, devops

I created two sub-domains test.xxxxxx.com and dev.xxxxxx.com, test.xxxxxx.com is working fine but the dev.xxxxxx.com is not working.

dev.xxxxxx.com is for hosting **Laravel API** and test.xxxxxx.com is for host **front end** for development purposes. The same

**test.xxxxxx.com conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.xxxxxx.com
ServerAlias www.test.xxxxxx.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/test.xxxxxx.com/html/
<Directory /var/www/test.xxxxxx.com/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**dev.xxxxxx.com conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName dev.xxxxxx.com
# This is for websocket requests
ProxyPass /ws ws://localhost:8090/
ProxyPassReverse /ws ws://localhost:8090/
ProxyPass /wss wss://localhost:8090/
ProxyPassReverse /wss wss://localhost:8090/

DocumentRoot /var/www/dev.xxxxxx.com/public/
<Directory /var/www/dev.xxxxxx.com/public/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]   
</VirtualHost>
```

**test.xxxxxx.com .htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

**dev.xxxxxx.com .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

**error.log**

```
[Thu Oct 08 06:25:03.080835 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7166] AH00163 Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Oct 08 06:25:03.080868 2020] [core:notice] [pid 7166] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Oct 08 06:58:55.476022 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7166] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Oct 08 06:58:55.591321 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27165] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Oct 08 06:58:55.591392 2020] [core:notice] [pid 27165] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Oct 08 07:45:13.216293 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27165] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Oct 08 07:45:13.333468 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7532] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Oct 08 07:45:13.333534 2020] [core:notice] [pid 7532] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Oct 08 07:48:35.893704 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7532] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Oct 08 07:48:36.048994 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9434] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Oct 08 07:48:36.049053 2020] [core:notice] [pid 9434] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Oct 08 07:49:01.736094 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9434] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Oct 08 07:49:01.965885 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9836] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Oct 08 07:49:01.965966 2020] [core:notice] [pid 9836] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

I enabled both sites and restart the **apache2**
but the dev is not working. Anyone please?

Comment: do u have 2 folder .? `var/www/dev.xxxxxx.com/public/` and `var/www/test.xxxxxx.com/html/` ?

Comment: yes @KamleshPaul.

Comment: Does it work if proxy code is commented out? In other words, would it work if all options are identically set?

Comment: You mean to remove the code which is for socket purpose??? @Tpojka

Comment: @Tpojka still not working, i removed that code

Comment: Check apache logs.

Comment: I found that its working out side of my company, seems like only my internet connection is interrupting, I disabled the firewall and do other diagnostics but still its not working with me only. My friends with other internet connection can access it. @Tpojka and Kamlesh

Comment: There must be logs of error that could point to cause of issue. Read that messages (and paste here). Apache's error log and access log.

Comment: @Tpojka i added the error log, the other access log only contains logs for other domains, not related to this one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222713/discussion-between-tpojka-and-imdad-ali).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that a local host with same domain `dev.xxxxxx.com` was set up in `hosts` file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`, I removed it from `hosts` file and it worked smoothly.